# SQL statement to get all customers with no orders TODAY(current date)

Tags: sql

The question is, how do I write a statement that would return all customers with NO Orders TODAY using sql join?

Tables : tbl_member ,tbl_order
tbl_member consist of id,name,
tbl_order consist of id, date, foodOrdered

Comment: so you have no indication of the member in tbl_order?

Comment: You can add a AND - Statement to your join like: "JOIN table ON t1.id = t2.id AND t2.date <> NOW" or something like

Comment: @Conny  this is unbelievable,it worked...but if I change my pc system date ...I get no order ....can u help me with a way to prevent that...maybe server date...

Comment: `Now` gets the current date of `System` only

Comment: depending on your SQL language you have different time variables, maybe current_date or something. If you want to order just add "Order by NOW" after your WHERE clause. you can also write the numbers of the columns you want to order by. ("Order by 1" orders by col 1)

Answer (score 1):

If you left join, the select where the table on the right is nulkl, it limits to the rows that DO NOT meet the join condition:

```
select t1.*
from tbl_member t1
left join tbl_member t2
  on t1.id = t2.id -- assuming that t2.id relates to t1.id
  and t2.date = current_date() -- today's date in mysql
where t2.id is null
```

Comment: So that means if I use the current_date()..whenever I change my PC system date ..noting is gonna happen ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming tbl_order date is a datetime (it probably should be) for sql server you could use something like:

```
declare @tbl_member table
(
id int,
fullname varchar(50)
)

declare @tbl_order table
(
id int,
orderdate datetime,
foodOrdered varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO @tbl_member VALUES (1, 'George Washington')
INSERT INTO @tbl_member VALUES (2, 'Abraham Lincoln')
INSERT INTO @tbl_member VALUES (3, 'Mickey Mouse')
INSERT INTO @tbl_member VALUES (3, 'Donald Duck')

INSERT INTO @tbl_order VALUES (1, '2017-07-01 13:00:00', 'Fish and Chips')
INSERT INTO @tbl_order VALUES (2, '2017-07-03 08:00:00', 'Full English')
INSERT INTO @tbl_order VALUES (3, '2017-07-25 08:00:00', 'Veggie Burger')
INSERT INTO @tbl_order VALUES (3, '2017-07-25 12:00:00', 'Bangers and Mash')

SELECT id, fullname FROM @tbl_member WHERE id NOT IN 
(SELECT id FROM @tbl_order 
WHERE CAST(orderDate as date) = CAST(GETDATE() as Date))
```

It helps if you specify what flavour database you are using as the syntax is often subtly different.